# CLion tutorial for GoogleTest: changing STATIC to SHARED library crashes

Tags: googletest, clion

I followed the tutorial here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/unit-testing-tutorial.html and got it all to work as promised (Windows 10 Pro, CLion 2021.1.2, Debug MinGW Lavavej + boost toolchain https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

I changed one word in `DateConverter_lib\CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_library(DateConverter_lib STATIC
```

to

```
add_library(DateConverter_lib SHARED
```

The project builds but no longer runs, printing

```
Test framework quit unexpectedly 
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

which, apparently, is a failure to load the DLL (shared library). Any advice for me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out that exit code means you are missing the shared library.(In windows case, DLL file.) When the library is shared, it means it is not linked to the binary you generated. So every time you run it, you need to specify the DLL location.

You need to make sure the configuration of `Google_Tests_run` (or whatever the test run/debug configuration you will use) has the shared library path in the environment variables. In your case, it should look like something like:

```
PATH=$PATH\;C:\Users\BrianBeckman\CLionProjects\DateConverter\cmake-build-debug\DateConverter_lib
```

Another option is to put the DLL file in the working directory. You can do it by adding a symbolic link in the direction where your executable is located to the DLL in the build directory. Or change the working directory in the run/debug configuration, but this only works when you only have one shared library location.

By the way, if you are using a UNIX-like system like Linux or MacOS, you don't need such configuration because cmake will write the location of shared library to RPATH. Unfortunately, Windows doesn't have a concept of RPATH for the DLL files.

Happy Testing!